# Materialized view with trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

Can i create trigger on materialized view? I'm using oracle 10g.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. Just be careful. This is what [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) says:

> If you create a trigger on a base
>   table of a materialized view, then you
>   must ensure that the trigger does not
>   fire during a refresh of the
>   materialized view. During refresh, the
>   DBMS_MVIEW procedure I_AM_A_REFRESH
>   returns TRUE.