# postgresql create trigger on materialized view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, materialized-views, triggers

I would like to have a field (produkt) in one table that references a view (owoce).

```
-- see definition of 'owoce' below
FOREIGN KEY (produkt) REFERENCES owoce(nazwa) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

It's forbidden in PostgreSQL (9.3), so I decided to create materialized view instead (it's probably even better - faster- in this case). It's said that materialized views can be used as ordinary tables.

My previously used ordinary view had a trigger that modified underlying table (see below), but when I change the view to materialized I got an error:

> 'komplety' is not a table nor view

**In Oracle it's possible to create a trigger on materialized views** ([Materialized view with trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037139/materialized-view-with-trigger))**, and what about PostgreSQL 9.3?
Maybe is there any other possibility to make a reference field to view?** I'd prefer to use standar view in this case.

*Sorry for mixing languages in my code, but my GUI directly uses table names.*

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW komplety AS
    SELECT nazwa, klient
    FROM produkty
    WHERE komplet = true;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_view_komplety()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
   BEGIN
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO produkty(komplet,nazwa,klient,jm) VALUES(true,NEW.nazwa,NEW.klient,'kpl.');
        RETURN NEW;
      ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
       UPDATE produkty SET nazwa=NEW.nazwa, klient=NEW.klient WHERE nazwa=OLD.nazwa AND klient=OLD.klient AND komplet=true;
       RETURN NEW;
      ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
       DELETE FROM produkty WHERE nazwa=OLD.nazwa AND klient=OLD.klient AND komplet=true;
       RETURN NULL;
      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_view_komplety_trig
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON
      komplety FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_view_komplety();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation that says, "You can't create a trigger on a materialized view."

Nevertheless, it appears that a materialized view isn't a view in the sense that you need it to be. For example, trying to drop a materialized view raises this error.

```
ERROR:  "komplety" is not a view
HINT:  Use DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW to remove a materialized view.
```

I think this lines up with what the current docs say about [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

> The name (optionally schema-qualified) of the table or view the
>   trigger is for.

Note that it doesn't say "table or view or materialized view".

You *can* write a trigger for a view that does the work of the foreign key constraint you'd *prefer* to use.

Comment: Thank you. I used trigger and an ordinary view. I don't know why I was so focused on the constraints, that I forgot about the most obvious solution. I spent hours walking around...